# Can not Reset Password : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, reset-password

I have a problem when Reset password, always get error

`Your password reset link has expired.`

I tried to trace code in file :

`vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountMangement.php`

in method :

`public function validateResetPasswordLinkToken($customerId, $resetPasswordLinkToken)`.

I did `print_r($_REQUEST);`, but always got `null` although the URL in reset password token in sent email has always the correct id and token, but when I try to print it, it is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the magento exception.So you need to go to class method `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword::execute()` and in catch statement log the exception.

Comment: I already tried, Could you check this please ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212340/reset-password-problem-magento-2